# AS3 Flash Player on Chrome remembers hardware settings even when hardware is not present

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, actionscript, flash

I am making a voice chat application and am accessing the microphone through the Flash Player. I check for the microphone via the Microphone.getMicrophone() function.

If the microphone is not connected the above function call output is null and thereby I tell the user, through a dialog box with an OK and SKIP button, that there is no microphone attached. If the user clicks on the OK button, I check for the microphone again else skip this step.

On Chrome, the flash player initially detects that no microphone is attached. I attach a microphone and it work fine. Now I refresh the page and remove the microphone again. Again the Flash Player checks for the microphone and the output of the above function is not null. I close Chrome and follow the above steps, it works fine again.

Does Chrome internally store the detected hardware settings anywhere? If yes, how can I clear it using AS3?

On Firefox and Internet Explorer, it works perfectly.